# React and Redux: create a variable to use in the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to create, in a project, a controller when the user logged-in.

Basically I would to save some values, not in the db, but in some variables that I can use in the project.

In my idea, this is the actions that the user should do:

1. The first time that the user logged in, the user will be redirect to a form should choose some values for two variables ( and i want to save these values, that they will be used in to prepoluate some field in the project ) - POST -
2. The user can change these values - PUT -
3. Retrieve the data that are saved - GET -

So I'm trying to create a reducer page, to manage these 3 "actions" that he could do.

It's the first time that created a reducers/actions of this type, so:

```
import { REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE } from 'app/shared/reducers/action-type.util';
export const ACTION_TYPES = {
    FETCH_DATA : 'FETCH_DATA',
    CREATE_DATA : 'CREATE_DATA',
    UPDATE_DATA : 'UPDATE_DATA'
};

export interface PersonInfo {
    info: {
        role?: string | number,
        environment ?: string | number
    }

}




const initialState: PersonInfo =  {
  info: {
      role: '',
      environment : ''
  }
}

// reducers

export default (state: PersonInfo=initialState, action): PersonInfo => {
    switch( action.type ){
        case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_DATA):
            console.log("FETCH DATA ", state)
            return {
                ...state
            };
        case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_DATA):
        case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_DATA):
        case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_DATA):
        case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_DATA):
        case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_DATA):
        case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_DATA):
            return {
                ...state
            };
        case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_DATA):
        case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_DATA): 
            return {
                ...state
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

// now I need to create the actions, and there I have some problems..

// 3. This should be the action to fetch data and to see if the values are populated
export const getData = info =>  {
    return {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_DATA,
        payload: info
    }
}

// 1. This should be the action to post data in the variables: (but I don't think it does anything useful .. I should connect my initialState to this function i believe)

  export const createData = entity =>  {
    const userInfo = {
        role: entity.role,
        environment: entity.environment
    }
    const result = ({
      type: ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_DATA,
      payload: userInfo
    });
    console.log("result ", result)
    return result;
  };
```

So my question is, how can i fix this actions/reducers to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat these options just like handling state in a single component, but with the mentality that it's for your global state (hence, Redux).  If your tree doesn't branch out to where component A has no way of talking to component B AND you need to access this state in either case, AND you are not changing this state constantly, I would recommend using `useContext` instead of Redux. This is a fundamental concept within React, and state isn't "RESTful". You are either initializing it, setting it, or reading it.

[Take 13 minutes and check out this video on useContext](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LrDIWkK_Bc)